# Mandrill doesn't log errors, but the email is never sent

Tags: heroku, mandrill

I have a rails app that in which I built a contact form.
It works locally with this configuration:

```
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: "smtp.gmail.com",
    port: 587,
    domain: ENV["GMAIL_DOMAIN"],
    authentication: "plain",
    enable_starttls_auto: true,
    user_name: ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"],
    password: ENV["GMAIL_PASSWORD"]
  }
end
```

Now I want to make it run on Heroku using Mandrill, so this is my production.rb

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
:address   => "smtp.mandrillapp.com",
:port      => 587,
:user_name => ENV["MANDRILL_USERNAME"],
:password  => ENV["MANDRILL_APIKEY"]
```

}

```
  # ActionMailer Config
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'myDomain.com' }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
```

When I visit the website, fill the form and click "send", this is the log:

> 2014-04-07T23:35:56.661073+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by
>   ContatoController#create as HTML 2014-04-07T23:35:56.661073+00:00
>   app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"???", "auth
>   enticity_token"=>"",
>   "contato"=>{"name"=>"test1", "email"=>"myEmail@email.com",
>   "message"=>"sdfsdffsd", "nickname"=>""}, "commit"=>"Send"}
>   2014-04-07T23:35:56.661073+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters:
>   {"utf8"=>"???", "auth
>   enticity_token"=>"5769b554vJsVK3KldK/EmSaN8yUF/z4S7LZdzSlZ6XE=",
>   "contato"=>{"name"=>"test1", "email"=>"myEmail@email.com",
>   "message"=>"sdfsdffsd", "nicknam e"=>""}, "commit"=>"Send"}
>   2014-04-07T23:35:56.668905+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1
>   /gems/mail_form-1.5.0/lib/mail_form/views/mail_form/contact.erb
>   (1.1ms) 2014-04-07T23:35:56.668905+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1
>   /gems/mail_form-1.5.0/lib/mail_form/views/mail_form/contact.erb
>   (1.1ms) 2014-04-07T23:35:58.200457+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   2014-04-07T23:35:58.200457+00:00 app[web.1]: Sent mail to
>   myEmail@gmail.com (153
>   0.1ms) 2014-04-07T23:35:58.200457+00:00 app[web.1]: 2014-04-07T23:35:58.200457+00:00 app[web.1]: Sent mail to
>   myEmail@gmail.com (153
>   0.1ms) 2014-04-07T23:35:58.209656+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path=/conta to host=myDomain.com
>   request_id=b3b2f599-a685-4968-97a1-9dd7a3508083 fwd="20
>   1.37.139.250" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=1558ms status=200 bytes=6107

But the e-mail never comes.
Mandril doesn't count as e-mail sent either.

Because I was using the informed e-mail as "from address", I changed to no-reply@myDomain.com and added it to mandrill's sending domain list. But still nothing happens.

What could be causing this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it out: somehow my Mandrill key in heroku config was different from the one given in Mandrill's website and it wasn't showing errors. I configured wit the correct key and it works now.